# why Coordinates object's heading attribute always return null in mobile safari?

Tags: safari, geolocation

I want to get Geo information through Geolocation API on mobile safari, but Coordinates object's heading attribute always return null. Does safari not support heading attribute?

Code blow:

```
window.onload=function(){
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successCallback,errorCallback);
    function successCallback(position) {
        var coords=position.coords;
        console.info(coords.heading);
    }
    function errorCallback(){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mobile Safari does not support the heading attribute, but it does support its own proprietary attributes.

```
  window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(e) {
       var heading = 'heading: ' + e.webkitCompassHeading +
                     '\n' + 
                     'headingAccuracy: ' + e.webkitCompassAccuracy;
       alert(heading);
  }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I leave this here because I wasted a full day with the same problem.
You are looking into the wrong API for getting the Orientation of the phone. The heading attribute in the geolocation is not the compas orientation but a direction calculated based on the movement of the phone. So if you are standing still heading is null. As soon you as you are moving the heading points into the direction of your movement. See this docu: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationCoordinates/heading

What you are looking for is the "deviceorientation" event. For iOS/Safari you have to manually request the feature first.
(This is Typescript code)

```html
const isIOS = !(
    navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/) &&
    navigator.userAgent.match(/AppleWebKit/)
);
if (isIOS) {
    (DeviceOrientationEvent as any).requestPermission()
        .then((response: any) => {
            if (response === "granted") {
                window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", this.receivedNewHeading, true);
            } else {
                alert("has to be allowed!");
            }
        })
        .catch(() => alert("not supported"));
} else {
    window.addEventListener("deviceorientationabsolute", this.receivedNewHeading, true);
}
```